# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception running Unit Tests using Junit in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm refactoring some unit tests, and I removed a dependency my team had from another team.

I refactored the code to point to our new library and began making sure old unit tests work but I am getting a Exception in "main" thread. I ran the tests prior and everything was working perfectly, so I am a bit confused. The only other thing I added was Spring context and core dependencies version 5.2.2.RELEASE. Below is the error snippet from IntelliJ:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:260)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.getInstanceForClassLoader(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:41)
at org.powermock.api.extension.reporter.AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.create(AbstractMockingFrameworkReporterFactory.java:35)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getMockingFrameworkReporter(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:140)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:119)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:202)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also checked my mockito/Powermock dependencies upon research and they appear to be the correct compatible versions based on the comptabitlity matrix, https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Below is some of my junit/mockito/powermock dependencies from my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.47</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.47</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Share exceptions as text not as image

Comment: Yes sir! updating now